# PS5 requires multiple power key press to turn on

Tags: ps5

Since few days, the power key of the PS5 needs a few presses for the Console to start. Earlier, it used to start with just one press, but I am observing that I need to press the power button 3-4 times.

Is this normal or a cause of concern?

Comment: How "stern" of a push are giving it? Looking at the style of button, I am wondering if maybe you aren't pushing it hard enough for it to actually engage the button, or maybe not centered enough.

Comment: @TimmyJim Normal push. It used to start in one push earlier.

Comment: Are you turning off the console completely or leaving it in rest mode?

Comment: @NirajShah Complete turn off

Comment: The button might be starting to break. Use the PS button on the controller to turn on the console instead (put in rest mode if required).